# Using iota subscripts in math mode

Tags: math-mode, symbols, greek

Is there a way to apply iota subscripts to arbitrary alphabets in the math mode?

An example is ῳ.

Comment: As in ᾳ ? Not really, not out of the box, what purpose do you have in mind? I mean, I'm sure you could make it happen but why?

Comment: Yes, I have some purposes and just curious to see if the iota subscripts can be applied in math mode.

Comment: What's an iota subscript? @Au101 ?

Comment: ᾳ is an example.

Comment: How do you make one not in maths mode? What is it made from? The letter alpha, obviously. But what else?

Comment: @cfr The iota is the greek letter ι, it's the Greek *i*. In Ancient Greek (not sure about Modern) it can form a sort of compound with the letters α η and ω where a small version is placed underneath: ᾳ ῃ ῳ. This is known as the iota subscript. These are read as diphthongs with the first vowel long: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iota_subscript

Comment: It's worth noting that according to Wikipedia at least, it was actually an innovation of the 12th century, invented for philological reasons, rather than something that would have been found in Ancient Greece. However you will see it in today's printings of Ancient Greek texts

Comment: @Au101 I know how to write an iota. What I meant to ask is how to make an iota subscript. In text mode, that is.

Comment: @cfr With a Greek keyboard and XeTeX or a Greek-language package? I always use XeTeX for Greek, but I think there is a LaTeX package for Greek out there somewhere. The iota subscript is a feature of the spelling of real Greek words, like the rough breathing, or the accents. It's a diacritic. It's not a Greek letter, where LaTeX generally provides basic support only for the individual letters of the Greek alphabet for use in maths. And then of course you have packages such as `textgreek` so that you can write β-decay or whatever

Comment: I must say, the idea of using it in math mode, and particularly with any (presumably Greek) letter is a bit bizarre to me, especially as it can only occur with the three letters I mentioned in actual Greek

Comment: @cfr `lgreek` can do it apparently: http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/lgreek/lgreekuse.pdf But I wouldn't go there anymore, I'd use XeTeX

Comment: ῳ is equivalent to ωι, which can be considered as an abbreviation for the latter form. The ι sound was originally pronounced but  was lost later so the form ῳ was introduced to capture the original  etymology perhaps. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iota_subscript for details)

Comment: OK. I don't have a Greek keyboard and I don't know how to input it directly. I thought there might be a macro version. (Presumably there may be somewhere.) I've seen it, I think. (Insofar as I see Greek, it is always Ancient. I don't know what it means but I know what it looks like, if you see what I mean.)

Comment: @cfr In `lgreek` there is `a|` I think

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can basically use anything as a centered subscript:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\adscriptiota}{{%
  \usefont{LGR}{cmr}{m}{n}\symbol{"7C}%
}}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\ai}[1]{{\mathpalette\doai{#1}}}
\newcommand{\doai}[2]{%
  \oalign{%
    $#1#2$\cr
    \hidewidth$#1\text{\adscriptiota}$\hidewidth\cr
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$\ai{\alpha}\ai{b}\ai{\gamma}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want special positioning under particular letters, you have to do it by hand. The case of letters with descenders is tough, as exemplified by `\gamma`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is the syntax \usefont{LGR}{cmr}{m}{n}\symbol{"7C} determine the form of the iota subscript here ?

Comment: @Johannes Yes, you can use other font families instead of `cmr`, provided they have support for LGR.

Comment: Sorry, I was not sure about the mechanism of displaying a image here. I was wondering it might be better to not use the letter b here but a more challenging one such as g here to show the position of iota subscripts.

Comment: @Johannes I'll do it.